# Cannot give url as json response in philsturgeon REST library codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

When I give the following as a json response

```
http://test.com
```

this is getting converted to

```
http:\/\/test.com
```

Where ever there is a `/` its getting converted to `/\`. Why does this happen?How can I give a proper response in this.

Please help

Comment: It is how json response should look like. On the other hand, when json is parsed, than you will get 'normal' URLs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does JSON encoder adds escaping character when encoding URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723243/why-does-json-encoder-adds-escaping-character-when-encoding-urls)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as if the url has been encoded. You can decode it with the following command

```
var url = "http:\/\/test.com"
var decoded_url = decodeURIComponent(url);
```