# About Turn List<String> to String With GSON

Tags: java, gson

I use gson to take List into String. Like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String youtubeListStr = gson.toJson(List<String> strList);
```

And then get this by :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
List<String> youtube_List = gson.fromJson(youtubeListStr, type);
for(String url : youtube_List){
    println(url);
}
```

But   I get the results:

```
{"value":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/mGBaWXelaM0"}
```

How to get the correct url?

```
https:\\www.youtube.com\embed\mGBaWXelaM0
```

I want to print like the above results.

Comment: I just tested your code: everything is printed ok, like you want. Looks like simple problem with your misunderstanding.

Comment: BTW `https:\\www.youtube.com\embed\mGBaWXelaM0` - is not correct URL. It should be: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/mGBaWXelaM0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct URI, it just has [escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723243/why-does-json-encoder-adds-escaping-character-when-encoding-urls) `\` in there.

If you want the value to print and not the whole json string then you need to parse the json line with Gson and extract the part you want.

```
JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(url);
JsonObject  object = element.getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement serviceElement = object.get("value");
```

Comment: I think that the OP means that he wants to print `https:\\www.youtube.com\embed\mGBaWXelaM0` as opposed to `{"value":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/mGBaWXelaM0"}`

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, everything is ok: `json` like `xml` has a set of escaped characters, one of them is `\`. So, when you will read values from this `json` back, it will be corrent url in wanted format.

*UPD-2*: BTW `https:\\www.youtube.com\embed\mGBaWXelaM0` - is not correct URL. It should be: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/mGBaWXelaM0`
*UPD*:

full code:

```
    List<String> strList = Arrays.asList("https://www.youtube.com/embed/mGBaWXelaM0", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/mGBaWXelaM0");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String youtubeListStr = gson.toJson(strList);
    System.out.println(youtubeListStr);

    Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
    List<String> youtube_List = gson.fromJson(youtubeListStr, type);
    for(String url : youtube_List){
        System.out.println(url);
    }
```

Will printout:

```
["https://www.youtube.com/embed/mGBaWXelaM0","https://www.youtube.com/embed/mGBaWXelaM0"]
https://www.youtube.com/embed/mGBaWXelaM0
https://www.youtube.com/embed/mGBaWXelaM0
```

So everything is correct.